# Laravel resource empty request parameters

Tags: laravel, rest, eloquent

When calling API route the data from query doesn't get passed to resource and the request doesn't contain any data from the query.

Route

```
Route::get('rooms', 'RoomController@index');
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
   $rooms = Room::get();

   return RoomCollection::collection($rooms);
}
```

Resource

```
public function toArray($request){
   return [
       'id' => $this->uid_room,
       'code' => $this->room_code,
       'name' => $this->name
    ];
}
```

Comment: what is RoomCollection::collection?

Comment: You have a `$request` object in the `toArray()` method. There you should be able to access the request parameters.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin the $request has empty parameters. I'm asking why that is

Comment: @kerbholz return new RoomCollection($rooms) gives same problems. Empty quest parameters

Comment: No parameters. Calling the route using Postman and browser both show same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `Room::all()` instead of `Room::get()`?

Comment: Didn't fixed it

Comment: That's not really an answer, is it? More of a comment

Comment: I don't know @kerbholz, I'm new to SO. My personal criteria is that if it can (possibly) solve the problem and I don't ask any additional info from the topic starter, then it's more of an answer; if I ask to clear some details, then it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
use App\Room;
use App\Http\Resources\Room as RoomResource;

public function index() {
        $rooms = Room::all();
        return RoomResource::collection($rooms);
}
```

In App\Http\Resources\Room.php

```
public function toArray($request){
   return [
       'id' => $this->uid_room,
       'code' => $this->room_code,
       'name' => $this->name
    ];
}
```

Comment: @gygram does this work for you? I fixed the mistakes you made.